# reading text message through matlab using AT commands and bluetooth

Tags: matlab, bluetooth, serial-port, sms, at-command

I want to read text message using Matlab as hyperterminal using AT commands and bluetooth as connection medium since I am new in it could somebody suggest that how can I do it.
I am using nokia c2-03 for sending the message but if you suggest any other phone  i can  that too

I connected my phone through USB, saw the Port name then connected it through matlab using

```
s=serial('COM1');
```

and then opened the port

```
fopen(s)
```

now I don't know what to do I mean now how can send at command to control the device.

PS I am sure that my device supports serial communication.

Comment: Android, iOS, Windows, Blackberry? Jailbroken/Rooted? How sure are you? Why? Seems like something fishy to me.

Comment: i thought AT commands are same for all...

Comment: My concern is that this is typically a security issue that would likely be blocked by the OS, especially in iOS where most everything is sandbox'ed